# select effect in pushbuttons

Tags: qt, symbian

Ive created an array of buttons with out using the designer.

```
cellBut[i][j]=new QPushButton();

connect(cellBut[i][j],SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onClickAction()));
```

these are arranged in rows , a calender sorta thing, and i want to select them when clicked once, jus to know tht ive clicked that particular date. It gives the default “pressed and released effect” but not the highlighted effect.

I want it do the highlighting jus like how the default calenderwidget does.

is there some highlight function thing. I found an autofill backgroundthing or setMask, but it does nothing, or i dont know how to use it.
or if i get a pointer of the selected date, does it have the function to select???

Guide me on this please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [setCheckable()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) function.

```
setCheckable(true);
```

The button will stay checked until clicked again.

Edit:
Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

I think you can change the background color of the button, and simulate the highlight effect, with something like:

```
button->setStyleSheet("background: red");
```

Comment: thank you bruno. 
the thing is , if once checked, i'l have to  click the date once agin to uncheck it right?, rather than that i wud like something like highlight. so tht only the currently clicked button is highlighted

cellBut[i][j]->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255);"); should change background color right? but it does not. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to use a [Button group](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qbuttongroup.html). From the documentation: *An exclusive button group switches off all checkable (toggle) buttons except the one that was clicked.*